# Increment QML property of top-level type in child type

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to Qt with QML. I'm trying to set a property at the top element called **buttonIndex** so that the child elements could change the property by incrementing the value in the Button element to make the name go from "Device 1" -> "Device 15". This is my QML code below:

```
Page {
    id: page_device
    width: 1024
    height: 600

    property int buttonWidth: 170;
    property int buttonHeight: 100;
    property int buttonIndex: 1;

    header: Label {
        id: label_header_devices
        text: qsTr("Devices")
        font.pixelSize: Qt.application.font.pixelSize * 2
        padding: 20
    }

    Item {
        id: item_devices
        width: 300
        height: 200
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        Column {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            spacing: 10

            Repeater {
                id: item_devices_rows
                model: 3

                Row {
                    spacing: 10

                    Repeater {
                        id: item_devices_columns
                        model: 5

                        Button {
                            id: button_device_
                            width: buttonWidth
                            height: buttonHeight
                            text: qsTr("Device ") + page_device.buttonIndex++
                            Material.foreground: Material.Pink
                            enabled: false
                            hoverEnabled: false
                            
                            // onClicked: Material.background = Material.Teal
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is unwanted. I get "Device 107", "Device 108", "Device 109" etc.. I need to have it go from 1-15. I tried using the signal **itemAdded** in the code and re-assigning the value of the **buttonIndex** to increment by 1 each time but that didn't work either. And also I need to store that buttonIndex for the Button type such like "item_device_button_1". Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: Actually, you can use the [Repeater.index](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#delegate-prop) instead of reinventing that by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @folibis mentioned, you don't need to create your own property for this. Repeaters (and ListViews, etc.) give delegates access a property called `index` that already does exactly what you want. The index is 0-based, so if you want it to start at '1', then just add +1.

```
Repeater {
    Button {
        text: qsTr("Device ") + (index + 1)
    }
}
```